# Aristotelian explanation of magnetism

Tags: magnetism, aristotle

How did Aristotle explain magnetism? As far as I know, there were only 7 postulates in Aristotelian mechanics:

The first hypothesis Earth is the center of the universe.

Second hypothesis All material objects are made of the four elements originally
proposed by Empedocles and later adopted by Plato, namely earth, water, air, and
fire.

Third hypothesis Each of these elements has its natural place, or physical
location, in the universe.

Fourth hypothesis According to the hypothesis of antiperistasis introduced by Plato, air ‘‘displaced’’ from the front of the stone moves to its back and ‘‘pushes’’ it forward. But as the ‘‘push’’ is transmitted from one point of the air to another, it slowly weakens and allows the natural motion of the stone to prevail. As a result, the upward motion slows down and eventually reverts to a downward motion, causing the stone to hit the ground. Aristotle modified slightly Plato’s hypothesis of antiperistasis, stating that our moving hand sets to motion successive layers of air, which, in turn, push the stone. As the ‘‘force’’ is transmitted from one layer of air to another, it decays and finally, the natural downward motion of the stone prevails.

Fifth hypothesis The sky and the heavenly bodies are made of a substance that is neither earth nor water, air or fire. It is a fifth element which, following the ideas of earlier natural philosophers (Philolaos, Xenophanes, and Parmenides), he named aether.3 The physical place of this fifth element was beyond the realm of fire, outside the Moon’s orbit.

Sixth hypothesis The laws governing the motion of celestial bodies are different from those governing motion on Earth. So Aristotle arrived at the conclusion that, while in the region of the universe inside the Moon’s orbit, the natural state of objects is rest, in heaven the natural state of objects is eternal circular motion.

Seventh hypothesis There can be no vacuum in nature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only an small account of Aristotle about magnetism in [*On the soul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Soul) (see chapter I.2 and I.5). He discusses [Thales of Miletus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales_of_Miletus) theory of the motion of lodestone. According to Aristotle, Thales associated the magnetic forces to the presence of "souls" inside the rocks (being alive/animated). According to a [*History of electricity*](https://books.google.fr/books?redir_esc=y&id=hkMPAAAAMAAJ&q=aristotle#v=snippet&q=aristotle&f=false) by Benjamin Park:

> Aristotle  reports  the  sayings  of  Thales  only  by  hearsay, and  then  with  extreme  caution:  the  first  being  that  every- thing is  full  of  gods,  and  the  second*  (and  it  is  this  which is  of  especial  importance  in  our  present  research)  that
>
> > Thales  too,  as  is  related,  seems  to  regard  the  soul  as somehow  producing  motion,  for  he  said  that  the  stone  has a  soul  since  it  moves  iron.

If Aristotle adhered fully to Thales hypothesis, it is not completely clear.